# How to delete to recycle bin in FinalBuilder

Tags: recycle-bin, finalbuilder

I'm finding that deleting a folder containing many files and subfolders in FinalBuilder is very slow. An an alternative, I could delete the folder to the recycle bin.

Anyone have any suggestions how to do this in FinalBuilder 5?

Answer (score 2):

You might have more luck using dos commands to access the recycle bin and then invoking those from FinalBuilder: http://www.chami.com/tips/windows/012497W.html

Answer (score 1):

I use use a dos command to run recycle.exe from [CmdUtils](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/).  This will delete to the Recycle Bin without confirmation:

recycle.exe -f

Answer (score 1):

The performance of FinalBuilder has been greatly improved.   I believe it was slow in Final Builder 5.X because of the way the log files were implemented.   This changed with Final Builder 6.X.  (I could have this wrong as it may have been the 4.X to 5.X upgrade that fixed logging)

Regardless, since every file deleted is logged it takes some time.

Key ways to speed up logging is to turn off "Live Log View" removes the need to repaint the screen every time a file is deleted.

Deleting to the Recycle bin most likely won't speed up the process.   But you can give it a try by using the [CmdUtils](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/) as recommend by Sean.